# TestNG and Spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testng

I am trying to inject spring bean into testng @BeforeClass but it is showing following error:

> ```
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not 
> autowire field: com.tais.automation.service.ExecutionDetailManager
> com.tais.automation.testing.Driver.executionDetailManager; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'executionDetailManager': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire method: public void
> com.tais.automation.service.impl.ExecutionDetailManagerImpl.setConvertUtils(com.tais.automation.util.ConvertUtils);
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'convertutils': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: com.tais.automation.dao.ClientDao
> com.tais.automation.util.ConvertUtils.clientDao; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'clientDao': Injection of resource
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for
> dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
> {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=,
> name=, type=class java.lang.Object, lookup=,
> authenticationType=CONTAINER)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>       ... 125 more
> ```

```java
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath*:/applicationContext.xml")                 
 public class Driver extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests  {

    @Autowired                                                          
    ExecutionDetailManager executionDetailManager;  

    @Override                                                    
    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun=true)                            
    protected void springTestContextPrepareTestInstance() throws Exception {

            super.springTestContextBeforeTestClass();                    
            super.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance();                    
    }


    @Parameters({ "Module"})       
    public void setUp(@Optional("") String varModule ) throws Exception {                           
    //At this point my code breaks

    String result=**executionDetailManager.getResult();**

   }

}



 public interface ExecutionDetailManager  {

 public String getResult();

}



@Service("executionDetailManager")                          
public class ExecutionDetailManagerImpl  implements ExecutionDetailManager
{    
    public String getResult() {
       return "testResult";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see this `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: `

Comment: @vogel612  the above problem is solved noe it is showing NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for executionDetailManager??

Answer (score 0):

the above problem of sessionfactory was resolved once i extended AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests  instead of AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests . But now i am getting the below error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'executionDetailManager' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at com.tais.automation.testing.Driver.setUp(Driver.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)